# Refreshing a table using CREATE TABLE, DROP and Rename

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, replication, locking, blocking

A read-only database (database1) is updated via log shipping every minute,
then a procedure queries multiple tables in it and refreshes a large table on database2.

For this process I

- run an "expensive" query against database1 and generate a new Table in database2 (Table_A_TEMP)

  ```
  BEGIN TRAN
  DROP TABLE Table_A
  RENAME Table_A_TEMP to Table_A
  COMMIT
  ```

Does it look too ugly? Otherwise I would have to create a very complex verifications and updates.

Suggestions to minimize locks?

Comment: SQL Server is going to have to take out exclusive locks to drop and rename objects. If something is trying to access the table while you are doing it I don't thing there is much you can do to limit the blocking.  What locks are you trying to minimize?  Are you refreshing Table_A with every log ship or on set intervals?

Comment: How is a read only database able to be updated?

Comment: Database1 is read-only, not database2.

Answer (score 0):

I have to update every minute. One person suggested me to rename the original table as well, I will try, it will probably be quicker, then I drop it after the commit.